# Javascript, Array shuffle but keeping a certain distance

Tags: javascript, arrays, distance, shuffle

I need a function to shuffle an array of elements, but, keeping a minimum distance of 2 between the elements.

Let-me explain my case, I have a non-stop input, that keeps sending-me words each 200ms. I also have an unique array with pre-defined words.

Each word I receive, I check if it is OK or NOT, if it's OK within my conditions, I want to put it in my array. But, in that moment, I don't need an unique array anymore, so probably I will have doubles in my array, matter of fact, I want to have doubles of the words which fits in my condition.

Ok, so, here is the problem, each OK word I receive, I want to put it in the array and then shuffle it, it can be a double, but, in this case I want to keep a distance between this word and the other same words in the array.

Example:
Unique array: [foo, bar, baz, qux]
I start the program, that send me words every 200ms.
Got: fubar > OK
Insert: [foo, bar, baz, qux, fubar]
Got: orange > OK
Insert: [foo, bar, baz, qux, fubar, orange]
Got: lime > OK
Insert: [foo, bar, baz, qux, fubar, orange, lime]
Got: qux > OK (DOUBLE)

Insert RIGHT WAY: [foo, bar, baz, **qux**, fubar, orange, lime, **qux**]
Insert RIGHT WAY: [foo, **qux**, bar, baz, **qux**, fubar, orange, lime]
Insert WRONG WAY: [foo, bar, baz, **qux**, **qux**, fubar, orange, lime]

The first has a distance of 3, the second, distance of 2...
The third and wrong, has a distance of 0.

Anyone can give-me a good method and/or logic to do this? For a case like, minimum distance = 2.

Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT 1:**
The user jfriend00 showed up the possibility of the array being fulled of doubles, assuming they all have the minium distance, and the next element to insert has no correct position to fit, then, I must not insert it.

---

**EDIT 2:**
I figured also that I must avoid insert in positions that could impossibilitate one of the next insertions, like this:

Got: apple > OK
(A) Insert RIGHT WAY: [baz, **qux**, fubar, orange, lime, *apple*]

Got: qux > OK (DOUBLE)
(A) Insert RIGHT WAY: [baz, **qux**, fubar, orange, **qux**, lime, apple]
(B) Insert WRONG WAY: [baz, **qux**, fubar, orange, lime, **qux**, apple]

Here, the insert be get "truncated" by the qux inserted at a distance 3 (B).

Got: qux > OK (DOUBLE)
(A) Insert RIGHT WAY: [baz, **qux**, fubar, orange, **qux**, lime, apple, **qux**]
(B) Insert WRONG WAY: [baz, **qux**, fubar, orange, lime, **qux**, apple]

Comment: Do you realize that it's possible to have so many dups of one item that you can't insert it in the array without it being next to another dup?

Comment: Now I do, indeed, in this case, I must not insert in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not simple, I must admit. Let's start with some helper functions:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var i = 0, t = 1, l = (this.length >>> 0) - 1;
    for (; i < l; t = ++i + 1)
        while ((t = this.indexOf(this[i], t)) !== -1)
            this.splice(t, 1);
    return this;
};
Array.prototype.count = function(item) {
    var i = 0, t = 0;
    while (i = this.indexOf(item, i) + 1) t++;
    return t;
};
Array.prototype.remove = function(item) {
    var i = this.indexOf(item);
    if (i !== -1) this.splice(i, 1);
    return this;
};
```

I hope the meaning is clear, even if the code may look obscure. There are polyfill for `Array.prototype.indexOf` for older browsers (IE8-, basically), too.

Now the code:

```
function shuffleArray(array, previous) {
    if (!array.length) return array;
    // The list of unique items in the array
    var univals = array.slice().unique(),
        idx, pivot, rest;
    if (previous != null)
        // The array can't start with the previous element
        univals.remove(previous);

    while (univals.length) {
        // We choose an element from the possible ones
        idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * univals.length);
        pivot = univals[idx];
        // We try to shuffle the rest of the array.
        rest = shuffleArray(array.slice().remove(pivot), pivot);
        // If we got a shuffled array, we're done.
        // Else, we remove our pivot element from the possible ones
        if (rest != null)
            return [pivot].concat(rest);
        else univals.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The usage would be:

```
shuffleArray(array);
```

You can add a second optional parameter to make it avoid to start with a certain element. It's used recursively inside the function itself. If you get `null`, then it's not possible to shuffle the array with the given constraints.

Keep in mind that this algorithm can be optimized. In particular, you you can change it so it's not recursive, but rather iterative and more suitable for larger arrays.

Comment: I generally avoid adding enumerable methods to the `Array` prototype because the moment someone writes code to iterate an array like `for (x in array)`, their code will break because it will iterate over your methods.  Now, you shouldn't iterate arrays like that, but people do so I avoid that practice.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right, extending `Array.prototype` is usually deprecated. But to me that's hardly the reason - it's more about possible conflicts with new methods defined in Ecmascript, and the fact that calling a method in the prototype is slower than calling a static function. I did like that for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Yeah, I like the cleanliness of adding methods to the prototype too.  It is less of an issue with other objects that aren't likely to get iterated with `for (x in obj)`.

Comment: Great! I did almost the same back there. =)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm for adding items one at a time.  The basic idea is this:

1. Get an item you want to add to the list
2. If the list is empty, just add it
3. If the list is not empty, then generate an array of all possible positions it can be added to the list
4. Randomly select one of those possible positions
5. Check if that position is legal by checking the item currently at that position and the one before it.  If it is legal, add it there between the two items you just checked.
6. If that position is not legal, then remove that position from the array of all possible positions and randomly choose another position.  Removing it from the array makes sure you don't try the same illegal position over again
7. Repeat until you've either found a legal position (so you inserted it there) or until you ran out of possible positions (there's no place to put it because you've check all possible positions)

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5xGV3/

```
var sourceOfItems = ["apple", "grapefruit", "orange", "lime", "pear", "peach", "apricot"];

function insertNextItem(list, item) {

    // special case an empty items array
    if (list.length === 0) {
        list.push(item);
        return true; 
    }

    // build an array of possible insertion positions
    // items.length + 1 means to add it at the end
    var possiblePositions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length + 1; i++) {
        possiblePositions.push(i);
    }

    // select random position, see if that is allowed
    // if not, remove it from the possibilities and select a new random position
    while (possiblePositions.length > 0) {
        var randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possiblePositions.length);
        var pos = possiblePositions[randIndex];
        // check if this position is allowed
        if (list[pos] !== item && (pos === 0 || list[pos - 1] !== item)) {
            // position is allowed, insert it and return
            list.splice(pos, 0, item);
            return true;
        } else {
            // was not allowed, so remove this possiblePositions choice
            // and let the loop try again
            possiblePositions.splice(randIndex, 1);
        }
    }
    return false;    
}

function buildList(sourceItems, num) {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        insertNextItem(items, sourceOfItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceOfItems.length)]);
    }
    return items;
}

function go() {
    var list = buildList(sourceOfItems, 20);
}
```

For a more general version that can handle any minimum distance, see the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LxWNa/

P.S. When viewing the jsFiddle, it's very interesting to look at the debug console output because it shows you what positions were tried that didn't work and what items could not be inserted in the array because there was no legal spot for it.

Answer (score 2):

This will not positively add the item afterward, but will randomly shuffle the array!
Maybe it will help inspire a way to only add the index afterward? Hope it helps!

```
//Shuffles an array randomly
var shuffle = function (arrayinput){
  //loops around shuffling for four times the length of the array
  for(i= 0; i<(4 * arrayinput.length); i++){
    //Math.random generates a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1
    //that multiplied by arrayinput.length gives us a random number between 0 and
    //the array length. Math.floor rounds the number down, so we have a pseudo-random
    //number between 0 and the array length - 1, which is all of the array's indexes.
    var a = arrayinput[Math.floor(Math.random() * (arrayinput.length))];
    //saves the value at index a as var b
    var b = arrayinput[a];
    //deletes the one random value at index a from the array
    arrayinput.splice(a, 1);
    //adds that random value back to the beginning of the array
    arrayinput.unshift(b);
  }
  //returns shuffled array
  return arrayinput;
}
```